# SOQL Query failing

Tags: apex, soql, lightning-aura-components

I am developing an app to work with custom sObjects.

In there I have a list of items, and the items are ordered via a hidden number Order__c.

I also have buttons with these fields, to move them  up or down. Basically, it swaps the field with the one below/above it (depending on if you click down or up).

I have two custom sObjects:

- Master object
- Child object

The child object has a master-child relation lookup to its master-object ID.
Therefore, an order is unique only in combination with its master-ID.

These are the steps to take:

- on button click, send an event
- in the list component, handle the event
- in the list controller function that handles the event, grab the item from the event, and create an action with a function in an apex controller (referenced in the list component)
- in the apex controller: execute a query to grab the below/above item
- set the order of both fields to the other one
- update the list of both fields (so that it's one DML call instead of two)

**The problem is: it's failing at the select query (line where first [SELECT ... is).**

> 13:52:24:004 FATAL_ERROR System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

See the code below.

I am certain it's supposed to work: the up button on the top item is disabled, as is the down button on the bottom item. I have used the workbench and tested the query (altough with literal strings and numbers instead of inserted variables) and then it works absolutely fine.

I've tried

- AND Order__c = :item.Order__c - 1
- AND Order__c = (:item.Order__c - 1)
- AND Order__c = :(item.Order__c - 1)
- AND Order__c = :order

The last one being what is displayed below. I've also tried with and without LIMIT 1 (as I am certain there can only be one item with the given parent and order), in the workbench it works fine, below it doesn't work at all.

```
 @AuraEnabled
public static List<childItem__c> moveField(childItem__c item, String direction) {
    childItem__c other;
    Decimal order;
    if(direction == 'up') {
        order = item.Order__c - 1;
        other = [SELECT Id, Order__c
                 FROM childItem__c 
                 WHERE Parent__c = :item.Parent__c
                 AND Order__c = :order
                 LIMIT 1
                ];    
    } else if (direction == 'down') {
        order = item.Order__c + 1;
        other = [SELECT Id, Order__c 
                 FROM childItem__c 
                 WHERE Parent__c = :item.Parent__c
                 AND Order__c = :order
                 LIMIT 1
                ];    

    }        

    if(direction == 'up') {
        item.Order__c = item.Order__c - 1;
        other.Order__c = other.Order__c + 1;
    } else if (direction == 'down') {
        item.Order__c = item.Order__c + 1;
        other.Order__c = other.Order__c - 1;            
    }
    List<childItem__c> updateList = new List<childItem__c>{item, other};

        try {
            update updateList;
        } catch(DmlException e) {
            System.debug('An unexpected error has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
        }

    return getItems(item.Parent__c);
}
```

If at all possible, I would like to use as few objects as possible, i.e. to remove the current Decimal order variable. It should however be understandable, so that's why I did include the 'other' sObject.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to be more specific about what you mean when you say it fails. If you get an error message, please include it verbatim.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I added the error message from the app logs.

Comment: What if you debug the order value before your query? Does it match the literals you expect?

Comment: order = field.Order__c + 1;
            System.debug('order = ' + order);
resulting in 
            14:29:47:002 USER_DEBUG [33]|DEBUG|order = 2
            so yes, it does match what I expect it to be.

Comment: So...is that what you expected? Is there actually a record for that value?

Comment: Yes. For the Parent__c I provide, there are four fields, with an order from the set of {1..4}. When I click 'UP' on the third option, it should select the item with Parent__c == clickedItem.Parent__c and Order__c = clickedItem.Order__c - 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your query it is expecting `List<childItem__c>`, but you are directly trying to assign to `Decimal other`. Which is causing the issue.

```
         [SELECT Id, Order__c
             FROM childItem__c 
             WHERE Parent__c = :item.Parent__c
             AND Order__c = :order
             LIMIT 1
            ];
```

You can change the below line to this:

```
 List<childItem__c> lstItem = [SELECT Id, Order__c
             FROM childItem__c 
             WHERE Parent__c = :item.Parent__c
             AND Order__c = :order
             LIMIT 1
            ]; 
if(lstItem.size()>0)
 other = lstItem[0].Order__c;
```

Comment: Please at least add *some* explanation...this idea may be in the right vein but sans explanation is not very helpful.

Comment: yes, doing that

Comment: That is correct. But given the theory that there should NEVER be more than one sObject matching the query, why would I want to use a list? I even explicitly stated I only want one object (with the LIMIT 1)...

Comment: Also, not trying to directly assing to Decimal, but childItem__c other ;)

Comment: Another comment: your last line should stop after lstItem[0];

Comment: @Santa Yeah pay attention to the types (`ChildItem__c other` seems fine). OP - List assignment is generally considered best practice to avoid `QueryException` when you're not certain the record exists. As for why that record is not being found...you need to do more debugging.

Comment: I tried your edit, then i don't get any errors, but the list size is 0. Because of that it doesn't edit any orders, and after exiting the if (which includes the swapping up to and including the try-catch update) it returns the getItems function, resulting in an empty list. What...? EDIT: the parent__c is not submitted to the function, according to the logs, which might be the reason why I don't get any items back. (which should also simply just f*cking work)

Comment: @AdrianLarson @ SantanuBoral I'm just going to accept this answer as the right one as it solved the primary problem, and ask a new question for the remaining problems.

Comment: I think the primary problem is that your query isn't finding the data, and disagree a new question is the right move here tbh.

Comment: Well I have been digging a bit further and apparently the item itself is never being sent with the event. So I think a new question might be in place, but about something waaay different than I previously suggested.